# PIL Image compression

Tags: python, image, optimization, python-imaging-library, image-compression

I'm working on a script that resizes and optimizes an image (Iphone pictures in this case) to be used on a website. So far I wrote this simple script that results in about 35% file size reduction, but I was hoping I could get the size down even more. Is there any way to optimize this script more? Any help is much appreciated!

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('file location')
newImage = img.resize((1024, 768), Image.ANTIALIAS)         

newImage.save('new file location', optimize=True, quality=95)

newImage.show()
```

Comment: One option would be to consider a smaller size and `quality` set to 85 or 75.

Comment: I tried that but the result is minimal unfortunately.

Comment: In Photoshop I seem to get the best size reductions by converting images to palletted with 32 or 64 colors (5 to 6-bits per component), and then saving them as .PNG or .GIF images. I believe you can do those same operations with `PIL`/pillow. What is the intended use of the new images?

Comment: I will give that a go! They are meant to be used on a website, hence the need for the small file size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try Google's Guetzli encoder with [pyguetzli](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyguetzli), it usually generates smaller jpeg file but takes a substantial amount of time, compare:

- original: 9.4M
- pil_1024*768_q95.jpeg: 638K
- pil_1024*768_q85.jpeg: 404K
- guetzli_1024*768_q95.jpg: 376K

original jpeg file is from [wiki common](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=42187203), By Diego Delso, CC BY-SA 4.0.

Comment: I tried using the pyguetzli library (looks promising) but when trying to run my script I get the following error:


`ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyguetzli/_guetzli.abi3.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN7guetzli7ProcessERKNS_6ParamsEPNS_12ProcessStatsERKSsPSs
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyguetzli/_guetzli.abi3.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyguetzli/_guetzli.abi3.so`

Comment: @Stefan it seems there are issues with linker on your machine, you could report issue at [pyguetzli's github](https://github.com/wanadev/pyguetzli/issues).

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that. Hopefully this can be resolved soon, excited to try this methode! Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Stefan I installed python3 from homebrew, could install pyguetzli successfully.

Comment: @georgesxh That might be the issue. I installed it using the download from the official python website (although that should not be such a huge difference, right?). 

Just tried installing pyguetzli using homebrew to be sure but this yielded the same results unfortunately.

Comment: @Stefan fine, hope that the maintainer could help you out.

Comment: @georgesxh Me too, thanks for your help anyway! Much appreciated!

Comment: I've posted the issue on their github and they came back with a couple of possible solutions, but so far none has worked. I've yet to try their latest idea, defining the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable with the path to the python libs installed by brew. Hopefully this will solve the issue.